# How to modify "Cache-Control" header in Drupal 5.x?

Tags: drupal, http-headers, private, squid, cache-control

We are using Drupal 5.x. We are experimenting with Squid as reverse proxy. Squid and Drupal are configured. Static content is getting cached.

For testing purposes, we would like to set "Cache-Control: public ..." on the 'authenticated' pages returned by Drupal.

We see that the headers are set in bootstap.inc.  We've modified all instances of "Cache-Control" header in that file, set it to 'public'. However, when we view the HTTP headers (in Safari's Web Inspector), we see "Cache-Control:private". For that reason, Squid is returning Cache MISS on those pages.

Question is - where exactly is this "Cache-Control" getting set to "private"? How can we change the "Cache-Control" header for authenticated users?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Pressflow (https://launchpad.net/pressflow/5.x) which is a fork of Drupal with built in cache control.

Comment: Thanks. Can it be used to cache certain pages for authenticated users (for example, a node view that hardly changes). I've just tested Pressflow (mentioned in link above). I see that the responses from drupal have "Cache-Control: private" set.  Does pressflow help us cache certain pages for authenticated users, or does it not cache anything for authenticated users?